# BST Successor Proof

Tags: proof-techniques, binary-trees, binary-search

I'm studying for my CS final and I can't seem to get the anywhere with one of the questions.

This is the question:

Prove that if a node in a BST has a successor, but has no right child, then its successor must be an ancestor. (We will consider only BSTs with distinct elements.)

I know that a successor is the node that replaces the deleted node, and that we only need to worry about this case when the node being deleted has two children, but I can't seem to start this proof.

Any help?

Comment: What have you tried, to prove it yourself?  Have you tried working it out by hand on a few small examples, to see if you can spot a pattern?  Also, to help make this question more findable by search, I suggest spelling out what the BST acronym stands for.

Comment: @D.W. I added my answer that I trued.

Answer (score 1):

This might depend delicately on how you define a successor. From what I understand of this and from your post, a **successor to a node `N` is the node that replaces `N` when `N` is deleted** (preserving the properties of BST). This definition doesn't necessarily mean that each node has a unique successor. Consider the following example:

```
10
  \
   14
  /
13
```

What is the successor to the node 14? It can just as easily be either `10` or `13`.

I think this might be a counter-example to your question's claim. Delete node `14` and a BST tree that results is

```
10
  \
   13
```

`14` had no right child *and* its successor is not its ancestor.

Am I not understanding something?

Answer (score -1):

This is my attempt - I'm not sure if it's correct or not.

Start proof:

- A successor is the node that replaces a node when it is deleted, while preserving the properties of the BST.
- The tree is traversed in post order (Left, Right, Node).

Consider the tree:

```
    A
     \
      B
     /
    C
```

The order in which the nodes are visited to delete node B is as follows:

C, B

C has already been visited.
 B’s successor must be A.

End proof.

Comment: To whomever marked me down, can you help me understand why I'm wrong?